# I want to display a blank field in the calculated column if both the reference fields are blank

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time, calculated-column-formula, formula, isblank

I want to display a blank field in the calculated column if both the reference fields are blank, but SharePoint displays the default date as `30-Dec-1899`.

Formula I used in Calculated column:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Actual Release Date]),TEXT([Forecast Release Date],"dd-mmm-yyyy"),TEXT([Actual Release Date],"dd-mmm-yyyy"))
```

**Updated requirements**:

If actual release is blank then it should consider the forecast release in the calculated column, if both dates are available then it should take the actual release date.

But when both the reference fields are blank, then it should leave the calculated value as blank instead of giving the default date (30-Dec-1899).

Comment: What if both fields are not blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below formula shows will show blank field in calculated column if both date fields are blank otherwise it will show "Both Date Fields are not blank".

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK([Actual Release Date]),ISBLANK([Forecast Release Date])),"","Both Date Fields are not blank")
```

**References**:

1. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).
2. [AND function](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/and-function-9ca21054-a466-477e-98bf-fc79e62afb3c).

**Update**:

Below formula meets all your requirements, please check using this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Actual Release Date]),IF(ISBLANK([Forecast Release Date]),"",TEXT([Forecast Release Date],"dd-mmm-yyyy")),TEXT([Actual Release Date],"dd-mmm-yyyy"))
```

[image]

Comment: If actual release is blank then it should consider the forecast release in the calculated column, if both dates are available then it should take the actual release date. But when both the reference fields are blank, then it should leave the calculated value as blank instead of giving the default date (30-Dec-1899). I tried using, =IF(AND(ISBLANK([Actual Release Date]),ISBLANK([Forecast Release Date])),"",IF(ISBLANK([Actual Release Date]),TEXT([Forecast Release Date],"dd-mmm-yyyy"),TEXT([Actual Release Date],"dd-mmm-yyyy"))), it works for blank condition but fails on the original requirement.

Comment: Try Updated formula from my answer.

Comment: Hard Luck!! :( Still not working for me on the original requirement, but blank condition is working as expected.

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? I guess all the requirements you mentioned in above comments are getting fulfilled.

Comment: If both fields are blank then result is blank. If both fields are not blank then it is taking Actual release date as a result. If Actual date is blank then it is taking Forecast release date as a result otherwise it is taking as Actual release date as a result.

Comment: I used the above formula, it gives blank field for all the conditions. @Ganesh Sanap

Comment: I have added a snapshot above.

Comment: Sorry Bro, It is workin. I was using the wrong fiels (SIGH) :) Thanks a lot for your help and time @Ganesh Sanap

Comment: Welcome. Please upvote (^) and accept it as answer so that it will help community to find the correct answers easily.

Answer (score 0):

Do a search on "excel if and formula" .  Here is an example from `exceljet.com`

```
=IF(AND(A1="this",B1="that"),"x","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ganesh's Formula is correct and you can change the "Both Date Fields" to your required text. 
[image]